# How to find recursively empty directories in Python?

Tags: python, directory-structure, subdirectory

Similarly to GNU `find`'s [`find . -type d -empty -delete`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/46326/863) I'd like to find empty directories including those with empty subdirectories (and subdirectories containing emtpy subdirs etc.), but **without deleting them**. Is there any existing solution or do I have to manually use `os.walk` (probably with `topdown=False` and keeping track of the empty subdirectories found so far)?

Comment: I would have tried to use `os.walk`, or `Popen` + `find` if I was sure to run on Unix/Linux

Comment: @SergeBallesta The former's my best guess so far, too. I was wondering whether there isn't a library function for it though... Or maybe a `find` module. That might simplify many things.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I [implemented it using `os.walk`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26775425/321973), hope it's sufficiently Pythonic...

Comment: @Close-vote I'm _not_ looking for a library recommendation, merely for a Pythonic way to achieve what `find` does (in a portable way). Of course "library XY implements this as Z" would be a valid answer nonetheless

Comment: I added a manual recursive solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here's my manual solution using `os.walk`. The function `is_empty` can of course be modified, e.g. to exclude hidden files, or in my example `desktop.ini`:

```
import os


def empty_dirs(root_dir='.', recursive=True):
    empty_dirs = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(root_dir, topdown=False):
        #print root, dirs, files
        if recursive:
            all_subs_empty = True  # until proven otherwise
            for sub in dirs:
                full_sub = os.path.join(root, sub)
                if full_sub not in empty_dirs:
                    #print full_sub, "not empty"
                    all_subs_empty = False
                    break
        else:
            all_subs_empty = (len(dirs) == 0)
        if all_subs_empty and is_empty(files):
            empty_dirs.append(root)
            yield root


def is_empty(files):
    return (len(files) == 0 or files == ['desktop.ini'])


def find_empty_dirs(root_dir='.', recursive=True):
    return list(empty_dirs(root_dir, recursive))


print find_empty_dirs(recursive=False)
```

Answer (score 13):

Here is a simple solution using a generator and `os.walk`:

```
import os

def find_empty_dirs(root_dir='.'):
    for dirpath, dirs, files in os.walk(root_dir):
        if not dirs and not files:
            yield dirpath

print list(find_empty_dirs())
```

I don't see why `topdown=False` is necessary, I don't think it changes anything.

This does consider directories that only contain empty directories to be non-empty themselves, but then so does `find . -type d -empty`.

Although, with some more testing, I see `find . -type d -empty -delete` *does* delete the empty subdirectories first, and then the higher directories if that made them empty. But using os.walk for that won't work, as it reads the list of subdirectories before descending, even with `topdown=False`.

A recursive solution that deletes empty subdirectory trees could be:

```
import os

def recursive_delete_if_empty(path):
    """Recursively delete empty directories; return True
    if everything was deleted."""

    if not os.path.isdir(path):
        # If you also want to delete some files like desktop.ini, check
        # for that here, and return True if you delete them.
        return False

    # Note that the list comprehension here is necessary, a
    # generator expression would shortcut and we don't want that!
    if all([recursive_delete_if_empty(os.path.join(path, filename))
            for filename in os.listdir(path)]):
        # Either there was nothing here or it was all deleted
        os.rmdir(path)
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Curious - ah, I see my mistake in the question, `find . -type d -empty` only works recursively the way I meant when using `-delete` as well. I'm afraid I have to fix my question, though your input is appreciated, a generator does sound nicer either way

Comment: I modified [my own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26775425/321973) to include a generator, but so far I have to store all empty subdirs found so far, which is why I require `topdown=False`. But maybe there _is_ an easier way